# How to add arrow of variable size to ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I couldn't find any solution which would produce a variable sized arrow - eg. one which starts small and then gets larger. This would be a nice elegant way to highlight an increase/decrease/trends in a graph. Ideally I would like to have the code following the ggplot way - see below where the arrow/ arrow tail starts small and culminates in larger thicker tail / arrow head towards the right size of the graph.

I have two partial answers which could be improved.

Some data

```
NAME <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
YEAR <- c(1, 5, 20, 10, 16, 11)
VALUE <- c(1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 8)
DATA <- data.frame(NAME, YEAR, VALUE)
```

Partial answer 1 = 'The ggplot way'

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DATA, aes(x=VALUE, y=YEAR)) + 
  geom_point(size=5, aes(colour=YEAR)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=1, xend = 8 , y=1, yend = 1), size=1.5, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.6,"cm"))) +
  xlab(expression(small %->% large))
```

The problem with this methods, I could not find a way to make one side of the arrow smaller and the other side of the arrow larger?

Partial answer 2 = "Sticking an image onto a graph". Inspiration for this code can be found from site "https://gist.github.com/scrogster/7fc5b7597b63585a00b6"

```
library(png)
library(RCurl)

arrowurl = "http://oztelefield.com/images/slider/growth/arrow.png" # any png of an arrow from google can work
arrow_logo = readPNG(getURLContent(arrowurl))

#utility function for embedding png images at specified fractional sizes in R plots
#places the logo centred on a specified fraction of the the usr space, 
#and sizes appropriately (respects aspect ratio)
logoing_func<-function(logo, x, y, size){
  dims<-dim(logo)[1:2] #number of x-y pixels for the logo (aspect ratio)
  AR<-dims[1]/dims[2]
  par(usr=c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  rasterImage(logo, x-(size/2), y-(AR*size/2), x+(size/2), y+(AR*size/2), interpolate=TRUE)
}

plot(y = YEAR, x = VALUE, xlab = "small --> large", pch = 16, ylab = "YEAR")
logoing_func(arrow_logo, x=0.10, y=0.90, size=0.15)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom grob and add it to the plot,

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

p <- qplot(c(2, 8), c(2,5)) + expand_limits(x=c(0,10), y=c(0,10)) 

my_arrow <- function(...){

  segmentsGrob(, arrow = arrow())  

}

p + annotation_custom(my_arrow(), xmin=2, xmax=8, ymin=2, ymax=7)
```

The tricky part is to create a custom grob for the arrow that has the correct angle etc. Here's one attempt.

---

For no good reason I like to think of grid units as having real and
imaginary parts, corresponding to relative and absolute sizes,
respectively.

```
dcplx <- function(u) unit(Re(u), "npc") + unit(Im(u), "cm")
```

Let's define two possible grobs to make the arrow: one from an image,
the other a custom grob.

```
img <- png::readPNG(RCurl::getURLContent("https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/245801/RedArrow.png"), native = FALSE)

arrow_logo <- rasterGrob(img, width = unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"))


arrow_grid <- xsplineGrob(x = dcplx(c(0+0i, 1-0.6i, 1-2i, 1+0i, 1-2i, 1-0.6i, 0+0i)), 
                          y = dcplx(c(0.5-0.1i, 0.5-0.4i, 0.5-2i, 0.5+0i, 0.5+2i, 0.5+0.4i, 0.5+0.1i)), 
                          shape = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,0), open=FALSE, 
                          gp=gpar(fill="red", alpha=0.2, col=NA))

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width=0.9, height=0.9))
grid.rect()
grid.draw(arrow_grid)
grid.points(x = dcplx(c(0+0i, 1-0.6i, 1-2i, 1+0i, 1-2i, 1-0.6i, 0+0i)), 
            y = dcplx(c(0.5-0.1i, 0.5-0.4i, 0.5-2i, 0.5+0i, 0.5+2i, 0.5+0.4i, 0.5+0.1i)),
            pch= "+", gp=gpar(cex=1))
popViewport()
```

[image]

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width=0.9, height=0.9))
grid.rect()
grid.draw(arrow_logo)
popViewport()
```

[image]

In order to join the two points, we need this grob to rotate and scale.
This is done by defining the right viewport at drawing time, where the
device cqn return the width and height separating the two points.

```
arrowGrob <- function(glyph = segmentsGrob(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 
                                           arrow = arrow(), 
                                           gp=gpar(lwd=2, col="red"))){
  grob(glyph = glyph, cl = "my_arrow")
}

drawDetails.my_arrow <- function(x, recording = FALSE){

  dx <- convertWidth(unit(1,"npc"), "mm", TRUE)
  dy <- convertHeight(unit(1,"npc"), "mm", TRUE)
  hypothenuse <- unit(sqrt(dx^2+dy^2), "mm")
  theta <- atan2(dy, dx)

  x$glyph$vp <- viewport(width = hypothenuse,
                         angle = theta*180/pi)

  grid.draw(x$glyph)

}

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width=0.8, height=0.8))
grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="grey95"))
grid.draw(arrowGrob())
popViewport()
```

[image]

We can now test the grob with ggplot2, using `annotation_custom`.

```
grid.arrange(p + annotation_custom(arrowGrob(), xmin=2, xmax=8, ymin=2, ymax=5),
             p + annotation_custom(arrowGrob(arrow_grid), xmin=2, xmax=8, ymin=2, ymax=5),
             p + annotation_custom(arrowGrob(arrow_logo), xmin=2, xmax=8, ymin=2, ymax=5),
             nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer, is there any chance you could add some basic information which would allow modification of the grob shape?

Answer (score 0):

With a series of segments:

```
ggplot(DATA, aes(x=VALUE, y=YEAR)) + 
  geom_point(size=5, aes(colour=YEAR)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, size = size),
               data.frame(x = seq(1, 7.99, 0.01), xend = seq(1.01, 8, 0.01), 
                          y = 10, yend = 10, size = seq(1, 3, l = 700))) +
  geom_segment(aes(8, 10, xend = 8.01, yend = 10), 
               size = 3, arrow = arrow(length = unit(1,"cm"))) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  xlab(expression(small %->% large))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks also for this solution, is there a way to change the colour to red for both segments. I am running into troubles with the continuous nature of the solution.

Comment: Just add `col = 'red'` _outside_ of the `aes` to both `geom_segment` calls.